# Inject OAuth2 token via reverse proxy

Tags: oauth-2.0, reverse-proxy

We have a service that sends delivery notification messages to a client via HTTP requests - meaning, the client must also act as a Server (must expose an HTTP endpoint) in order to receive these notifications.

Some of our clients are asking that our requests authenticate against their endpoints via OAuth. We would prefer to implement this using a third-party so as to avoid having security features implemented in-house (and avoid security issues/not well-handled edge cases that we could end up introducing); More specifically, we'd prefer to have a reverse-proxy.

The idea would be that our service would send a request to the client through the reverse proxy, which would identify that the request is missing a token and would be responsible for getting a token and injecting it into the request.

I googled for this but couldn't find anything; perhaps I'm not searching for the correct keywords. Is there a packaged/"market" reverse-proxy solution for this? Or perhaps a programmable reverse-proxy that could bootstrap a solution for us?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two approaches for this:

- have an oauth2 client library in your own code to handle the oauth2 authentication flow for your app. Most programming languages have an oauth2 client so you wouldn't re-implement anything and have a secure authentication mechanism,
- use a proxy that implements an oauth2 client so it would do that part of the flow for your service but I'm not sure it exists. I couldn't find anything also related to this because of the fact that most of the languages have an oauth2 client that's readily available.

I hope you find the solution to your problem :)